# C - Conflicting Types Error/Realloc

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

Beginner to C programming, learning as part of university work

For the code as mentioned below - i have been recieving a 'Conflicting Types' error for calling the function get_dog ***line 23*** and ***line 32***

Errors:

```
    task11-1.c:23:35: error: assigning to 'dog' (aka 'struct dog') from incompatible
task11-1.c:19:30: error: expected ';' after expression
    new_array = &(*new_array)realloc(array->ptr,array->size*sizeof(new_array));
                             ^
                             ;
task11-1.c:23:37: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_dog' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog(*new_array);
                                    ^
task11-1.c:23:35: error: assigning to 'struct dog' from incompatible type 'int'
        array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog(*new_array);
                                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
task11-1.c:19:30: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with
      'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
    new_array = &(*new_array)realloc(array->ptr,array->size*sizeof(new_array));
                             ^~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
task11-1.c:32:12: error: conflicting types for 'get_dog'
struct dog get_dog(struct dog_array *array){
           ^
task11-1.c:23:37: note: previous implicit declaration is here
        array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog(*new_array);
                                    ^
task11-1.c:34:24: error: member reference base type 'int ()' is not a structure
      or union
    scanf("%s", get_dog.dog_name);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
task11-1.c:36:24: error: member reference base type 'int ()' is not a structure
      or union
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_id);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
task11-1.c:38:24: error: member reference base type 'int ()' is not a structure
      or union
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_age);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
task11-1.c:40:12: error: returning 'int ()' from a function with incompatible
      result type 'struct dog'
    return get_dog;
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dog{
    char dog_name[20];
    int dog_id;
    int dog_age;
};

struct dog_array{
    int size;
    struct dog *ptr;
};

void add(struct dog_array *array){ //dog_array *array was intended as a parameter as shown in sample code
    int *ptr;
    struct dog *new_array;
    array -> size++;
    new_array = &(*new_array)realloc(array->ptr,array->size*sizeof(new_array));
    if (new_array)
    {
        array->ptr = new_array;
        array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog(*new_array);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Out of Memory! Cannot add dog details!\n");
        array->size--;
    }
}

struct dog get_dog(struct dog_array *array){
    printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    scanf("%s", get_dog.dog_name);
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_id);
    printf("Enter Salary: ");
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_age);

    return get_dog;
}

int main(){
    int input;
    struct dog_array array={0, NULL};

    printf("Enter in an option:\n");
    printf("1. Add to Array\n");
    printf("2. Print all Array\n");
    printf("3. Exit Program\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    switch(input){
        case 1:
            printf("You have selected option 1\n");
            add(&array);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("You have selected option 2\n");
            //print_data(dog);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("You selected to exit, exiting...\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the task ive been following:

[Task Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUd4k.jpg)

[Sample code I followed for add function as given by university](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lsyn.jpg)

Would anyone be able to correct my code as to why im getting the conflicting types error?
And the get_dog function, would i have called it correctly in the function along with formatting the realloc() function correctly?

Thank You

**UPDATE: Inserted New Code, taken in comments - more errors**

Comment: Can you please add some comments on the line the errors are on? And please copy-paste the actual errors, in full and complete, into the question body? Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please don't spam tags. [Edit] your question and remove tags that are not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Just a hunch, but don't name the struct "dog" and the type "dog" as well.  Since you're likely to use the typedef name, call the struct "dogStruct".  Same thing for dog_array.  Also, you probably meant to pass a dog instance to get_dog?

Comment: Drop the `&` from `scanf("%s", &r_dog.dog_name);` as the name of an array already gets converted to a pointer to its first element there.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `add(dog_array *array);`? Remove it. And change `case '1'` `case '2'` etc to `case 1` `case 2` etc.

Comment: @Neil, using the same name for both the struct and the typedef shouldn't cause any problems, it is a common practice.

Comment: What is this line expected to do? `new_array = &(*new_array)realloc(array->ptr,array->size*sizeof(new_array));`

You dereference a pointer and don't use the return value of `realloc`. Should this be a type cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following errors are in the provided code:

- Function 'struct dog get_dog(struct dog_array *array)' should be declared before used.
- For typecasting and sizeof operator, use type not the variable.
- 'get_dog' variable was not declared in the function 'struct dog get_dog(struct dog_array *array)'

Following is corrected code but may be logically incorrect. Because intention of this program is not much clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dog{
    char dog_name[20];
    int dog_id;
    int dog_age;
};

struct dog_array{
    int size;
    struct dog *ptr;
};

struct dog get_dog(struct dog *array);

void add(struct dog_array *array){ //dog_array *array was intended as a parameter as shown in sample code
    //int *ptr;
    struct dog *new_array;
    array -> size++;
    new_array = (struct dog*)realloc(array->ptr,array->size*sizeof(struct dog));
    if (new_array)
    {
        array->ptr = new_array;
        array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog(new_array);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Out of Memory! Cannot add dog details!\n");
        array->size--;
    }
}

struct dog get_dog(struct dog *array){
    struct dog get_dog= *array;
    printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    scanf("%s", get_dog.dog_name);
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_id);
    printf("Enter Salary: ");
    scanf("%d", get_dog.dog_age);

    return get_dog;
}

int main(){
    int input;
    struct dog_array array={0, NULL};

    printf("Enter in an option:\n");
    printf("1. Add to Array\n");
    printf("2. Print all Array\n");
    printf("3. Exit Program\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    switch(input){
        case 1:
            printf("You have selected option 1\n");
            add(&array);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("You have selected option 2\n");
            //print_data(dog);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("You selected to exit, exiting...\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment expression:

```
array->ptr[array->size-1] = get_dog();
```

is wrong - the type on the left side is `dog*` but on the right is `dog`.

BTW, the get_dog() is called without arguments...